# Firebase storage file is accessed by everyone

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have restricted rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /{allPaths=**} {
    allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

but every one can access and download file from this link.
[image]

how should I restrict downloading from this link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download URLs by definition give read-only access to the file, and are not affected by the security rules.

If you want to control access to the file, you should not generate a download URL and instead access the file through the SDK only.

Comment: As I understood, when I clicked that hyperlink downalod Url was generated, before that it did not exst? Can someone else generate that download url?

Comment: To be able to generate/request a download URL in the SDK you need to have `.read` permission on the file. Since the download URL is unguessable (due to the token in it), users can only have it if you gave the token from the console (in your screenshot) to them, or if they have read permission to the file already.